# Python - catch only specific tokens from file and ignore one line and multi line comments and new-lines

Tags: python-3.x, regex, compilation, tokenize

Given a file (**this is the input**), I have to tokenize it (so to speak) - I have to retrieve only the following 5 types of tokens:

1. **identifiers** - A sequence of letters, digits, and underscore ('_') not starting with a digit - like the built-in function - isidentifier().
2. **integers** -  A decimal number in the range 0 .. 32767.
3. **strings** - '"' A sequence of Unicode characters not including double-quote or newline '"'.
4. **keywords** - as specified in the below code.
5. **Symbols** - as specified in the below code.

So I actually tried to retrieve only those relevant chunks from the file, but some content of comments may seem to match a symbol/keyword, and that's the problem.

**The code I have come up with, to retrieve only the relevant tokens:**

```
   identifier_regex = '\w+'
   integer_regex = '\d+'
   string_regex = '\".*\"'
   keyword_regex = ('class|method|function|constructor|int|boolean|char|void|'
                    'var|static|field|let|do|if|else|while|return|true|false|'
                    'null|this')
   symbol_regex = '{|}|\[|\]|\(|\)|\.|,|;|\+|-|\*|\/|&|\||<|>|=|~'
   composed_regex = r'({}|{}|{}|{}|{})'.format(identifier_regex,
                                               integer_regex,
                                               string_regex,
                                               keyword_regex,
                                               symbol_regex)
```

- Possible types of comments:

```
// Comment to end of line

/* Comment until closing */

/** API documentation comment */
```

- **So I think the problem is only in identifying the empty-lines, comments (one-line comments - `//` OR multi-line comments - `/**  */`) - for that I have come up with that Regex:**
  `\s+|//.*`

**1. But `\s` can also ignore relevant whitespaces from the file, no?**

**2. `//.*` is for catching one-line comments.**

**3. Regarding multi-line comments, I don't know how to handle them, as it can be spread over multiple lines...**

**Sample input and output example**:
[Here is an image displaying a sample input and its expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IbUG.png)

Comment: What does a sample input look like, what is the expected result, what code have you tried using your defined regex formulations and what results did you get?

Comment: In order for us to help you, it is necessary that you show your effort and submit data to be used to reproduce your problem. While providing an image is helpful, it doesn't allow for reproducing the issue. Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details.